# Kendo UI ASP.NET Core: NullReferenceException in custom editor template

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, kendo-grid

I want a TimeSpan editor with separate fields for days, hours, minutes and seconds.
I have a custom editor tempalte, a model binder, a model binder provider and registered the latter.

While rendering the page a NullReferenceException occurs.

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Internal.ExpressionMetadataProvider.<>c__DisplayClass0_0`2.<FromLambdaExpression>g__modelAccessor|0(Object container)
>     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ModelExplorer.get_Model()
>     at Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent.WidgetFactory`1.NumericTextBoxFor[TValue](Expression`1 expression)
>     at Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent.WidgetFactory`1.IntegerTextBoxFor(Expression`1 expression)
>     at AspNetCore.Views_Shared_EditorTemplates_TimeSpanNumeric.ExecuteAsync() in E:\Source\MCT\MCT\Views\Shared\EditorTemplates\TimeSpanNumeric.cshtml:line 5
>     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageCoreAsync(IRazorPage page, ViewContext context)
>     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageAsync(IRazorPage page, ViewContext context, Boolean invokeViewStarts)
>     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderAsync(ViewContext context)
>     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Internal.TemplateRenderer.Render()
>     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Internal.TemplateBuilder.Build()
>     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.HtmlHelper.GenerateEditor(ModelExplorer modelExplorer, String htmlFieldName, String templateName, Object additionalViewData)
>     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.HtmlHelper.Editor(String expression, String templateName, String htmlFieldName, Object additionalViewData)
>     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.HtmlHelperEditorExtensions.Editor(IHtmlHelper htmlHelper, String expression, String templateName, Object additionalViewData)
>     at Kendo.Mvc.UI.GridBoundColumn`2.GetEditor(IHtmlHelper helper, HtmlEncoder encoder)
>     at Kendo.Mvc.UI.Grid`1.<>c__DisplayClass69_1.<InitializeEditors>b__2(IGridBoundColumn column)
>     at Kendo.Mvc.Extensions.EnumerableExtensions.Each[T](IEnumerable`1 instance, Action`1 action)
>     at Kendo.Mvc.UI.Grid`1.ProcessSettings()
>     at Kendo.Mvc.UI.WidgetBase.RenderHtml(TextWriter writer)
>     at Kendo.Mvc.UI.WidgetBase.ToHtmlString()
>     at Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent.WidgetBuilderBase`2.WriteTo(TextWriter writer, HtmlEncoder encoder)
>     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Internal.ViewBuffer.WriteToAsync(TextWriter writer, HtmlEncoder encoder)
>     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderLayoutAsync(ViewContext context, ViewBufferTextWriter bodyWriter)
>     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderAsync(ViewContext context)
>     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ViewContext viewContext, String contentType, Nullable`1 statusCode)
>     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext actionContext, IView view, ViewDataDictionary viewData, ITempDataDictionary tempData, String contentType, Nullable`1 statusCode)
>     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewResultExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext context, ViewResult result)
>     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewResult.ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
>     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultAsync(IActionResult result)
>     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextResultFilterAsyncTFilter,TFilterAsync
>     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContext context)
>     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext[TFilter,TFilterAsync](State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
>     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultFilters()
>     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextResourceFilter()
>     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext context)
>     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
>     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
>     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeAsync()
>     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
>     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointRoutingMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
>     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
>     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

The editor template:

```
@model TimeSpan    
@{
    if (Model != null) {
        @Html.Kendo().IntegerTextBoxFor(model => model.Days).HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 30px;" }).Spinners(false)@:.
        @Html.Kendo().IntegerTextBoxFor(model => model.Hours).HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 30px;" }).Spinners(false).Max(23)@: :
        @Html.Kendo().IntegerTextBoxFor(model => model.Minutes).HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 30px;" }).Spinners(false).Max(59)@: :
        @Html.Kendo().IntegerTextBoxFor(model => model.Seconds).HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 30px;" }).Spinners(false).Max(59)
    }
}
```

The kendo ui grid rendering the editor template:

```
@(
        Html.Kendo().Grid<MctDataViewModel>().Name("grid")
        .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create())
        .Pageable()
        .Scrollable()
        .Editable(e => e.Enabled(true).Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
        .Columns(c => { c.Command(cmd => { cmd.Edit().Text(" "); cmd.Destroy().Text(" "); }) ;
            c.Bound(m => m.Id);
            c.Bound(m => m.SequenceNumber);
            c.Bound(m => m.SequenceName);
            c.Bound(m => m.StepNumber);
            c.Bound(m => m.StepName);
            c.Bound(m => m.ParallelNumber);
            c.ForeignKey(m => m.RowType, (System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData[nameof(MCTRowType)], "Key", "Value");
            c.ForeignKey(m => m.TimeType, (System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData[nameof(MCTTimeType)], "Key", "Value");
            c.Bound(m => m.TimeNeeded).EditorTemplateName("TimeSpanNumeric");
            c.ForeignKey(m => m.InventoryType, (System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData[nameof(MCTInventoryType)], "Key", "Value").EditorTemplateName("GridNullableForeignKey");
            c.Bound(m => m.ByInventoriesUnits);
            c.Bound(m => m.ByInventoriesUnitsPerDay);
        })
        .DataSource(ds => ds.Ajax()
            .Sort(s => { s.Add(m => m.SequenceNumber); s.Add(m => m.StepNumber); })
            .Create(c => c.Action(nameof(MCT.Controllers.HomeController.CreateGridDate), "Home"))
            .Read(r => r.Action(nameof(MCT.Controllers.HomeController.ReadGridData), "Home"))
            .Update(u => u.Action(nameof(MCT.Controllers.HomeController.UpdateGridDate), "Home"))
            .Destroy(d => d.Action(nameof(MCT.Controllers.HomeController.DeleteGridDate), "Home"))
            .Model(m => {
                m.Id(mct => mct.Id);
                m.Field(f => f.TimeNeeded).DefaultValue(TimeSpan.Zero); })
        )
)
```

The service configuration:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
    // Add framework services.
    services
        .AddMvc(options => {
            options.ModelBinderProviders.Insert(0, new TimeSpanModelBinderProvider());
        })
        .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2)
        // Maintain property names during serialization. See:
        // https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/194
        .AddJsonOptions(options => options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver());

    // Add Kendo UI services to the services container
    services.AddKendo();
}
```

Even telling the framework to use the modelbinder explicitly in the view model doesn't change the issue.

```
    [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinder(typeof(TimeSpanModelBinder))]
    public TimeSpan TimeNeeded { get; set; }
```

The model binder is never called. The modelbinderprovider is called from another  request on a page used to navigate to this page. So the registration of the provider seems to work.

What am I missing? How can I get asp.net core to render my custom editor?

Kind regards Bernd

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately not. Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: not yet sorry .